# How To Display Option Weight In Opencart?

Tags: opencart

I am using Opencart for my ecommerce website.

In available Options option name and price are only displayed. I want to display the weight and points. Please help me to display weight and points values in available options. Please check the image attached in this post. I want to display weight and points near to price.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SKVF.jpg

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about administering of OpenCart and contains no programmatic related problem. Questions of this type should be asked on OpenCart forums or searched through Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log In to admin panel

```
catalog/options
```

Click on Insert Option

```
Option Name: Kilogram
Type:Radio
```

Add option Value

```
20G
50G
100G
```

Go to

```
catalog/product/
```

Edit Product and in option tab type Kilogram it will auto suggest you and now you can update price eg

```
Option Value:20G
Quantity:1
Price:20
```

You can modify according to requirement. 
Hope this helps